# Python dataclass: create property dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I have a dataclass, I'd like to dynamically create property device_group after evaluating another property device_name. I'm currently doing it with @property decorator and it works if I access it with instance.device_group .

```
@dataclass
class Device:
    device_name: str
    uplinks: list
    @property
    def device_group(self) -> str:
        # do something here with self.device_name
        return device_group
```

But the class instance won't have this property unless you try to access it with instance.device_group

```
  "unknown_device": {
    "device_name": "unknown_device",
    "uplinks": [
      {
```

Can the instance generate the device_group dynamically right after it was created?
Or I better to call device_group() somewhere else and then assign result to the device_group property explicitly?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? It looks like you want `dataclasses.asdict(my_device)` to contain `device_group` from your example output. Is that the case?

Comment: You can add a property to a *class* any time you want: `Device.device_group = property(the_getter)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [post init processing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Device:
    device_name: str
    uplinks: list
    device_group: str = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.device_group = self.device_name + "_group"
```